# What is the meaning of “Product of cosets”

Tags: group-theory, terminology, products

I came across with explanation of

> For (left)cosets to act like a group, following should be satisfied.
>
> $x \cdot y \in (xN)(yN)$.
> i.e $(xN)(yN) = xyN$

And the speaker said “$x$ times $y$ must be in the product of two cosets”

I was confused because as far as I know, the product between two sets $X$ and $Y$ is set of pairs $(x,y)$ with cardinality of `card(X) * card(Y)` which doesn’t make sense in this context. My question is

What is the definition of “product of $xN$ and $yN$”?

My second question is that the notion “$xyN$“ means normal subgroup N respect to $x \cdot y$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation they are referring to is the set-valued product $A\cdot B=\{ab\,:\, a\in A,\, b\in B\}$. The goal is to find conditions on the subgroup $N$ such that the set of left cosets of $N$, endowed with said product, is a group.

It turns out that the condition which guarantees the aforementioned is $N$ being normal. In that case, the group of cosets of $N$, with the projection $\pi:G\to \operatorname{cosets}(G,N)$, $\pi(x)=xN$ is a possible construction for the quotient group $G/N$, i.e. the data of a group $H$ and a map $\pi:G\to H$ such that for all groups $F$ and for all maps $f:G\to F$ such that $\ker f\supseteq N$ there is exactly one map $f':H\to F$ such that $f=f'\circ\pi$.

The notation $xN$, where $x\in G$ and $N<G$, refers the the set $\{xy\,:\, y\in N\}$, which may also be described as $\{g\in G\,:\, x^{-1}g\in N\}$, or as the equivalence class of $x$ with repsect to the equivalence relation $a\sim_N b\iff a^{-1}b\in N$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the product of two group $A$ and $B$ is set of $a \cdot b$ instead of pair $(a,b)$ right?

Comment: And also I’ve noticed that in context of group theory, you can omit the operator $\cdot$ and just write $ab$ right?

Comment: No. Those are two different things: the so-called *direct product* of two (or more) groups is the set $G\times H$ (respectively, $\prod_{i\in I} G_i$) endowed with componentwise product $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac,bd)$ (respectively, $[a\cdot b]_i=[a]_i\cdot [b]_i$ for all $i\in I$). This has several interesting universal properties. Sometimes (for instance, this time) it is usefult to consider the "set of products" of the elements of two subsets of some group: I named it $A\cdot B$ for pedantry, but it is commonly denoted as $AB$.

Comment: So.. the universal product definition in group theory is something else but the one from my question can be defined as $(xN)(yN) = \{ x \cdot y : x \in xN, y \in yN \}$ am I right?

Comment: Essentially yes, but not with the same $x$ and $y$ for everything.